# Python/pandas KeyError issue with user-defined functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Why do these two functions work properly and run with no errors?

```
def avgSalespWpY(df, weekStart_col_name, sku_col_name, order_col_name):
  df['SKU_WEEK'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df[weekStart_col_name]).week
  grouped_data = df.groupby(['SKU_WEEK']).mean().reset_index()
  return grouped_data[['SKU_WEEK', 'R_ORDER_QT']]

def avg_sales(df, prediction_window):
  earliest_date = prediction_window['WEEK_START_DT'].min()
  filter_date = df[df['WEEK_START_DT'] < earliest_date]
  avg_sales_df = avgSalespWpY(filter_date, 'WEEK_START_DT', 'SKU', 'R_ORDER_QT')
  prediction_window['SKU_WEEK'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(prediction_window['WEEK_START_DT']).week
  avg_sales_df.columns = ['SKU_WEEK', 'OA_SPW']
  avg_sales_total = avg_sales_df['OA_SPW'].mean()
  prediction_window = pd.merge(prediction_window, avg_sales_df, how = 'left', on = 'SKU_WEEK')
  prediction_window = prediction_window.loc[:, prediction_window.columns != 'SKU_WEEK']
  prediction_window['OA_SPW'] = prediction_window['OA_SPW'].fillna(avg_sales_total)
  return prediction_window
```

But these two do not work and run an error?

```
def avgSalespMpY(df, weekStart_col_name, order_col_name):
  df['SKU_MONTH'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df[weekStart_col_name]).month
  grouped_data = df.groupby(['SKU_MONTH'])[order_col_name].mean()
  return grouped_data

def avg_salesMY(df, prediction_window):
  earliest_date = prediction_window['WEEK_START_DT'].min()
  filter_date = df[df['WEEK_START_DT'] < earliest_date]
  avg_sales_df = avgSalespMpY(filter_date, 'WEEK_START_DT', 'R_ORDER_QT')
  prediction_window['SKU_MONTH'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(prediction_window['WEEK_START_DT']).month
  avg_sales_df.columns = ['SKU_MONTH', 'OA_SPW']
  avg_sales_total = avg_sales_df['OA_SPW'].mean()
  prediction_window = pd.merge(prediction_window, avg_sales_df, how = 'left', on = 'SKU_MONTH')
  prediction_window = prediction_window.loc[:, prediction_window.columns != 'SKU_MONTH']
  prediction_window['OA_SPW'] = prediction_window['OA_SPW'].fillna(avg_sales_total)
  print(prediction_window['OA_SPW'])
  return prediction_window
```

This is the error I am getting when I run the second function (avg_salesMY):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:

5 frames
pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: 'OA_SPW'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 'OA_SPW'
```

The output for the first function (avgSalespMpY) is what we expect and is as follows:

```
SKU_MONTH
1     535.687921
2     577.925649
3     611.837803
4     678.377140
5     496.411170
6     601.806244
7     688.770197
8     574.510967
9     636.203457
10    876.896305
11    719.614757
12    553.642329
Name: R_ORDER_QT, dtype: float64
```

I am very confused what is going on because the two segments are almost identical. There is an issue happening accessing the OA_SPW column but the one code is above the other, so why does it all of a sudden not want to run properly?

The first segment is supposed to take in data and find the overall average sales per week of year in the first segment and the second is supposed to take in prediction data and add in the output of the previous data. The second segment is supposed to take in data and find the overall average sales per month in the first segment and the second is supposed to take in prediction data and add in the output of the previous data. The biggest difference is that one's results is week by week and the other is based on month.

Comment: What does your SKU_WEEK table look like?

Comment: `104252    22
104253    23
104254    24
104255    25
104256    26
104257    27
104258    28
104259    29
104260    30
104261    31
104262    32
104263    33
104264    34
104265    35
104266    36
104267    37
104268    38
104269    39
104270    40
104271    41
104272    42
104273    43
104274    44
104275    45
104276    46
104277    47
Name: SKU_WEEK, dtype: int64` This is the output for SKU_WEEK